# Add list elements to the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and a dictionary. How can I add each element of the list to the dictionary?

```
list1 = ['March', 'April', 'May'] 
list2 = [{'surname': 'john March'}, {'surname': 'April O\'Neil'}, {'surname': 'David May'}]
```

What I need is:

```
list3 = [{'month':'March', 'surname': 'john March'}, {'month':'April', 'surname': 'April O\'Neil'}, {'month':'May', 'surname': 'David May'}]
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably [start with a basic tutorial on Python](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Dictionaries)

Comment: Are both lists supposed to be in the same order, or is your sample data ordered just by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update each dictionary item:

```
list1 = ['March', 'April', 'May'] 
list2 = [{'surname': 'john March'}, {'surname': 'April O\'Neil'}, {'surname': 'David May'}]

for i, item in enumerate(list2):
    item.update({'month': list1[i]})
    list2[i] = item

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[{'surname': 'john March', 'month': 'March'}, {'surname': "April O'Neil", 'month': 'April'}, {'surname': 'David May', 'month': 'May'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.5 or greater, you can zip the two lists together and then perform a comprehension on the resultant list of tuples to merge each string into each dictionary.

```py
[{**{'month': a}, **b} for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an efficient one, but considering `list1` elements are arranged in some other order. Then you can try this:-

```
for dt in list2:
    for ls in list1:
        if ls in list(dt.values())[0]:
            dt['month'] = ls
```

Output:-

```
[{'surname': 'john March', 'month': 'March'}, {'surname': "April O'Neil", 'month': 'April'}, {'surname': 'David May', 'month': 'May'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below simply:

```
list3 = []
for month, my_dict in zip(list1, list2):
    my_dict.update({'month': month})
    list3.append(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'surname': 'john March', 'month': 'March'}, {'surname': "April O'Neil", 'month': 'April'}, {'surname': 'David May', 'month': 'May'}]
```

`zip` is better and much faster than using `enumerate`, also it avoids using nested `for` loops that increases the time complexity to O(2)

Answer (score 0):

honestly i would follow billkw suggestion just tweak it a bit to make it more readable and user-friendly

```
[{'month': month, 'surname': surname['surname']} for month, surname in zip (list1, list2)]
```

As a output, you will get:

```
[{'month': 'March', 'surname': 'john March'}, {'month': 'April', 'surname': "April O'Neil"}, {'month': 'May', 'surname': 'David May'}]
```

I hope that will resolve your problem